# Unable to connect to Snapchat outside of Home Wi-Fi

Tags: iphone, network, wifi

I've noticed that on my iPhone 5, Snapchat can only connect to the Internet when I'm in my apartment Wi-Fi. Anywhere outside of that, I receive the following message when I try to open the app.[image]

What's strange is that I connect to all of my other apps that require Internet connection just fine outside my home Wi-Fi, but not Snapchat.

Comment: did you try to restart your phone ?

Answer (score 1):

You may have disabled cellular data for Snapchat, meaning that it will only work when it has a Wi-Fi connection and will not ever use your cellular data. [Here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201299) is a guide from Apple on how to enable cellular data for your apps.

If this doesn't work, try going to the App Store and verify that your Snapchat app is up-to-date.